# The form freezes when I use Thread.Join(), how to prevent?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I want to show the time interval that the 2 threads are finished. There are 2 Textboxes, 1 label and a button on my form. I am using the following code, but the forms freezes when I use thread Join() method. How I can solve it?

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ThreadingApp {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public void func1()
        {
            for ( long i=0; i <= 2000; i++)
            {
                this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    textBox1.Text = i.ToString();
                }));
                Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
        }

        public void func2()
        {
            for (long i = 0; i <= 200; i++)
            {
                this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    textBox2.Text = i.ToString();
                }));
                Thread.Sleep(20);
            }
        }
    
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
            Thread th1 = new Thread(func1);
            Thread th2 = new Thread(func2);
            s.Start();
            th1.Start();
            th2.Start();
            th1.Join(); th2.Join();
    
            s.Stop();
            lblTime.Text = s.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString();
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a deadlock. You are blocking the UI thread until the threads are finished (that's what `Join` does), and the threads depend on callbacks from the UI thread in order to complete their job (that's what `Invoke` does).

Comment: So how to solve it?

Comment: You could use the `BeginInvoke` instead of `Invoke` to avoid the deadlock, but most probably you won't see the textboxes updated during the threads execution. If you don't like that, then just avoid calling `Join`. If you absolutely need to call `Join`, then most probably you are using the wrong tool for the job. You don't need `Thread`s, you need `Task`s and async/await.

Comment: but when I use BeginInvoke it  does not work like a multi threading program. i.e.It doesn't allow me to relocate the until finishing all threads. But Join work properly in console application.

Comment: Console apps are free threaded, while GUI apps require that all interaction with the GUI happens through a dedicated thread, called the UI thread. This intricacy makes the GUI apps more delicate than the Console apps, because blocking the UI thread can cause the UI to become non responsive, which is a situation that nobody likes, and especially the end users. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use tasks instead of threads.

```
private async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
    s.Start();

    var task1 = Task.Run(func1);
    var task2 = Task.Run(func2);

    await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);

    s.Stop();
    lblTime.Text = s.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString();
}
```